# Proving that sum of matrices, of irreducible representation, corresponding to elements from conjugacy class is proportional to identity

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem [Link to problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB958.png).

I thought I could go about it by using Schur's second lemma which states that [Schur's second lemma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duQhO.png).

I tried to "see" the matrix $A=\displaystyle\sum_{T \in K}^{} \phi(T)$ from my problem as the matrix B from Schur's second lemma and essentially show that A commutes with all matrices of the $\phi$ irrep. Namely,

$A\phi(g)=\displaystyle\sum_{T \in K}^{} \phi(T)\phi(g)=\displaystyle\sum_{T \in K}^{} \phi(Tg)$

and

$\phi(g)A=\displaystyle\sum_{T \in K}^{} \phi(g)\phi(T)=\displaystyle\sum_{T \in K}^{} \phi(gT)$.

So what I now need to prove is $Tg=gT, \forall g\in G, T \in K$. To me, this would mean that the conjugacy class K is actually the center of the group since all of its elements commute with all elements of the group. This is where I am stuck.

Is this the right path toward the answer? Is there also another route that I can take?

Thank you

Comment: It's not true that $Tg=gT$ for all $g \in G$ and $k \in K$, but it is true that $Tg = gT'$ where $T' = g^{-1}Tg \in K$,and so $\sum_{T \in K} \phi(Tg) = \sum_{T \in K} \phi(gT)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.